# VSCode unable to discover python unittest

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-unittest

Seems like a rite of passage for using VSCode. Trying to setup python with unittest as my test configuration. Seems like all the tricks I have tried did not work. Here is what I know:

1. The folder structure can run fine with `python3 -m unittest` so we know the tests are discoverable (this is not an issue of including `__init__.py` files).
2. The `PYTHONPATH` is pointing to the repository properly (so this is not a `PYTHONPATH` issue)
3. `python.analysis.extraPaths` are pointing to the repository properly (`extraPaths` are set)
4. If I change the configuration to use `pytest` config instead of `unittest`, the tests become discoverable. Simply by changing the config to use `pytest` instead of `unittest` seems to make the difference.

You can find a repo that reproduces the issue [here](https://github.com/e-dnx/vscode_issue_001).

If someone is better versed in VSCode or Python please let me know what the issue is with `unittest` configuration that I show in the repo. Could it be a bug? I could not find anything on the other answers or bug reports that do not fall within the previous 3 categories.